# Custom Drupal Module not creating any tables

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Anything specific I need in the module file?

Install File

function module_install() {

```
//lets create the school database
$create_table_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
```

`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `principal_name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `school_name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `computer_serial_no` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";

```
db_query($create_table_sql);


//lets create the student database
```

$create_table_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `principal_name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `school_name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `computer_serial_no` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";

```
db_query($create_table_sql);
```

}

/**
 * _UNINSTALL hook
 *
 *  This function is run to uninstall the module.
 *
 */
function module_uninstall() {

```
// Delete the DB
db_query("drop table table1");
db_query("drop table table2");
```

}

Info File Just in Case

```
; $Id$
```

name = My Module
description = This module deals with blah blah
package = Somepackage
core = 6.x

version = "6.x-1.0"
core = "6.x"

Comment: It seems you are using Drupal 5 code for Drupal 6.
Drupal 6 has new database functions that allow you to abstract from such details, and write code that is compatible with all the database engines supported by Drupal.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using hook_install and hook_schema.

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_schema/6

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_install/6

For installing and uninstalling, hook_schema will make it more consistent and easier to debug, without writing SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to write your own DDL queries - use the [Schema API](http://drupal.org/node/146843) instead.